# Detect if user is using an iDevice

Tags: php, ios

Is there a way to detect if a user is using an iDevice WITHOUT reading the user-agent (which could easily be spoofed)? I want to have a mobile version (which will have no captcha), but desktop version will have captcha, so I want to use any other methods of checking other than UA-checks.

Comment: With PHP there's no perfect solution. All the data passed via HTTP can be faked.

Comment: Hi, why you want to check?. Captcha is for checking if the user is a machine or a human. In iPhone there can only be a human starting the app. You know what i mean? :)

Comment: Okay, but faking UA is a child's play. Is there any advanced detection?

Comment: @Retterdesdialogs He wants to protect his site against browser pretending to be a mobile device by spoofing the user-agent information!

Comment: @alexxus "Is there a way to detect if a user is using an iDevice". He wants to check if a user is using the iDevice. But you have not to check because who else could use the iDevice? :) I know what you mean, but because of the captcha thing i thougt he just want to check if it is a real user or a machine.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why are you using a captcha at all? Is this an interactive website or simply API calls from the application?

Answer (score 2):

According to what I know, you can't detected  mobile phones without user-agent. In fact, there is no any other function that check the mobile device..

You can check this lightweight class for detection of moblie devices:

https://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Answer (score 1):

First, as @bwoebi said, there is no other way to reliably check to see if they are on iOS.

However, you could say something like; OK, mobile devices have a screen size < Y * X, so I could just check the screen size. Unfortunately, this is also easily spoofed - by *resizing the browser window*.

In the end, it's probably not a good idea to skip Captcha for anyone. Just use it or don't - hackers are smart enough to set the user agent or resize thier browser. Also, it's not like people on Mobile can't solve Captchas.

Comment: Do you know if iOS browser sends any additional headers?

Comment: @user2342080 No, but again, any HTTP headers are going to be easy to fake. You'll probably need to just make your mobile users solve Captcha just like everyone else.

Answer (score 0):

I just used mobile detect about 30 min ago, it works PERFECTLY and easy to implement all you put in your code is:

```
// Check for a specific platform with the help of the magic methods:
if( $detect->isiOS() ){
    // do code here
}
```

and it will do that code. easy to use.
Just put `include 'includes/Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();` at the top of your page and it works fine.

[Mobile Detect.net](http://mobiledetect.net/)